# Android set TimePickerDialog at specific time

Tags: android, view, time, dialog, picker

I wish my TimePickerDialog is set by default to 19.00. How can I get this?

```
public void ora(View v) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    myDialog = new TimePickerDialog(Promemoria_giornaliero.this, new OnTimeSetListener() {

    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {


    txtTime.setText(hourOfDay + ":" + minute);

    }
    }, calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE), true);
    myDialog.show();

    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're currently supplying `calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE)` as the default hour and minute. Replace them with `19, 0`.

Comment: no, this is not accepted:  `calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 19), calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE, 0), true); `

Comment: Remove the calendar altogether. Just integers `19` and `0`.